# Why pointer of type int (*ptr)[10] requires address of the array and not just array itself

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Array returns pointer to the first element. I have simple code as below:

```
int a[10] = {1,2,3};//Filled three elements
int (*ptr)[10];//pointer to an array of 10 ints
ptr = a;
```

I am getting below warning.

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

If i modify the pointer definition as shown below then there is no warning

```
ptr = &a;
```

Why does the first assignment results in warning? Does &a returns integer pointer to array of 10 elements? Pls help to understand. Thanks

Comment: In most cases (except `sizeof` and `&`) arrays decay to pointers. `ptr = a` here `a` decays to type `int *`. But it is the pointer to the first element, not the pointer to the array. `ptr = &a` here `&a` is of type `int (*)[10]` and is the pointer to the array. Also note that the physical address of the first element and the array is the same, the only difference is the type.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? (many compilers also state the types invloved, which should make it crystal clear even)

Answer (score 2):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Except for the `sizeof`, `&` and `alignof` operator, arrays decay to pointers.

```
int a[10] = {1,2,3};//Filled three elements
int (*ptr)[10];//pointer to an array of 10 ints
ptr = a;
```

In the assignment `ptr = a`, `a` decays to a pointer to int (`int *`), which points to the first element.

```
int a[10] = {1,2,3};//Filled three elements
int (*ptr)[10];//pointer to an array of 10 ints
ptr = &a;
```

Here `&a` is of type `int (*)[10]`, which is a pointer to an array of 10 ints and has the same type as `ptr`. It is the proper way to assign a pointer to an array.

Also note that the value itself is the same for `a` and `&a`, the only difference is the type.

Comment: You forgot `alignof` Sidenote: there is no guarantee the value of two pointers of different type have are identical. E.g. for a type-aware instruction set, the type could be encoded in the value.